# Python 3 dynamically assign base class

Tags: python, class, python-3.x

I am writing a simple chess program to practice my OOP in python 3 and was wondering how to dynamically change (before class creation) the base class for a class definition. My class structure is this.

- abstract Piece class -> various derived pieces
- Board class, has a composite of derived Pieces, and 8x8 matrix, and some methods
- abstract Interface class -> CLI or
- abstract Interface class -> GUI (also subclassing Tkinter)
- Game class (for processing the game logic and main loop), which currently has a Board class member.

I initially implemented the Game class as having an interface data member that is defined during **init** but I'm finding myself sending a lot of the other internal Game data to the Interface composite member. I feel it would be more elegant to have the Game class be a subclass of either Interface subclass so the it could access their methods directly (and make them abstract).

However I want a version of the Game class that can do this dynamically so that I don't have to code it twice or inherit from both and make runtime decisions on which base class to use. I've currently done this by nesting the Game class inside a function like so.

```
def Game(ui):
    class Game(ui):
        ...
    return Game()
```

The crummy naming is part of the reason I don't like this solution. I want to be able to call the Game class on its own without explicitly using or acknowledging that I'm doing anything out of the ordinary.

Is there a way to do this with a metaclass or a class decorator? I have only been able to get them to affect class attributes, not the parent classes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `class` statement is "syntactic sugar" for

```
type(name, bases, dict)
```

You can create such a dynamic class using `type` like this

```
>>> class ui():
...     def start(self): print("Started!")
... 
>>> Game = type("Game", (ui,), {})
>>> game = Game()
>>> game.start()
Started!
```

Comment: Thanks @gnibbler, but I had to modify this a little to keep any of the new attributes that the Game class introduced by using      `Game = type("Game", (ui,), dict(Game.__dict__))` instead. Also, I hadn't realized the syntactic sugar of the class statement though, so thanks for that!

Answer (score 3):

You *could* use a very simple metclass here, but that's overkill.  You can just swap out which class you're using as the base class based on whatever condition you want:

```
>>> class Foo: pass
... 
>>> class Bar: pass
... 
>>> x = 3
>>> class Game(Foo if x < 3 else Bar):pass
... 
>>> Game.__bases__
(<class '__main__.Bar'>,)
```

Note that this isn't really any different than the formalism you have.  However, if I was to use your code, I wouldn't create the `Game` class and the instance all in the function.  I would do something like:

```
def Game_Factory(base):
    class Game(base):
         ...
    return Game

Game1 = Game_Factory(base1)
Game2 = Game_Factory(base2)

game1_instance = Game1()
game2_instance = Game2()
```

This gives you much easier access to the `Game` class (rather than needing to inspect an instance to get it).

Comment: This is probably the cleanest way of doing this outside of refactoring my class setup.